# Rails model set boolean when record updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model that I want to set a boolean to false whenever it is changed. Taht way I can reprocess it later to make sure the related records are up to date. I've tried a few things, but keep getting myself into a loop.

**/app/model/contest.rb**

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :results, dependent: :destroy

  after_update :set_contest_not_updated

  def set_contest_not_updated
    self.contest_updated=false
    self.save
  end

  def set_contest_updated
    self.update_column(:contest_updated_at, Time.now)
    self.update_column(:contesy_updated, true)
  end
```

**Expected action:**

```
  contest.update_atrributes(flag_that_effects_scoring: true)
```

I would expect that is the above is run, the **contest.contest_updated** boolean would be set to false and only be set to true when the **contest.set_contest_updated()** method is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course calling `save` in the `after_update` callback will get you into a loop. It keeps saving over and over again until the end of time.

However, `before_update` should get the job done.
PS: Don't call `save` on `*_save` and `*_update` callbacks. This will always get you into loops.

```
  before_update :set_contest_not_updated

  def set_contest_not_updated
    self.contest_updated = false
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will never work as when your `after_update` is called, it will invoke another `after_update` call and you will get the stack level too deep message.

The best solution is to have a foriegn key in another table/model such as contest_updates.

If you want your solution however, set the flag in a before_update filter